# How can I select data from two tables using an inner join and insert directly into a third table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with schemas as shown below:

```
user.table1
pid       => varchar
timestamp => timestamp
sid       => varchar

pid  timestamp    sid  attribute1  attribute2  ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1    2020/01/20   10   ...         ...         ...
2    2020/02/28   10   ...         ...         ...
3    2020/03/01   10   ...         ...         ...
4    2020/04/08   20   ...         ...         ...
5    2020/05/31   20   ...         ...         ...
6    2020/06/30   20   ...         ...         ...
7    2020/06/31   20   ...         ...         ...
8    2020/07/31   20   ...         ...         ...
```

```
user.table2
pid  => varchar
text => blob

pid  text
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1    xxx
2    abc
3    def
4    yyy
5    sss
6    abc
7    rrr
8    fff
```

I need to create a third table that should contain the information shown below:

```
user.table3
pid  timestamp    sid  text
-------------------------------
1    2020/01/20   10   xxx     
2    2020/02/28   10   abc     
3    2020/03/01   10   def     
4    2020/04/08   20   yyy     
5    2020/05/31   20   sss     
6    2020/06/30   20   abc     
7    2020/06/31   20   rrr     
8    2020/07/31   20   fff
```

Any idea how to do the select, inner join, and the insert in one SQL statement?

The reason I want to do it in one SQL statement is that I don't want to pull the information from the DB into Java and then write it back to the DB. I did the latter earlier, but that is running very slowly.

Currently, even the select I wrote below is not working.

```
select 
  table1.pid, table1.sid, table1.timestamp, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(table2.text,10,1)) 
from user.table1 inner join user.table2 
using pid 
where pid in ('1', '2');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn your select into an insert statement

```sql
INSERT INTO USER.table3(pid, sid, timestamp, text)
    SELECT t1.pid,
           t1.sid,
           t1.timestamp,
           UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (t2.text, 10, 1))
      FROM USER.table1 t1 INNER JOIN USER.table2 t2 ON (t1.pid = t2.pid)
     WHERE t1.pid IN ('1', '2');
```

Comment: Thank you @EJ. It worked perfectly for me

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer then so others do not spend time coming up with a solution if you already have a solution.